# React redux props cannot be accessed in render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I currently have a problem displaying some results from the redux state tree. In my console it shows me that the current object has arrived after calling this.props.walletStocks (stored in the redux state tree).

[image]

However, when I run the following code, it tells me that this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'] is undefined, and therefore has not arrived yet.

```
render() {
    return(
       {this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'].map((stock) => console.log(stock))}
    );
}
```

I know it's a problem with asynchronous data, I just really don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try checking against a falsey value before iterating: `this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'] && this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'].map(. . .)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper solution would set a loading state when starting the async data request and update it once the async data loading is done (e.g. using the Promise API). Then use that loading state to determine what is rendered.

Somewhere in your redux actions:

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_WALLET_STOCKS,
        loading: true,
    })
    .then(fetch('https://YOU_API'))
    .then(json => json.json())
    .then(walletStocks => dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_WALLET_STOCKS,
        walletStocks,
        loading: false,
    });
```

Provide the loading state to your component as well and in `YourComponent` render based on that flag:

```
render() {
    return(
       {this.props.loading
        ? 'loading...'
        : this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'].map((stock) => console.log(stock))}
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for it to load and then display. Try checking this.

```
render() {
return(
   {this.props.walletStocks && this.props.walletStocks['wallet4'].map((stock) => console.log(stock))}
);
```

}

Comment: Check your mapStateToProps function maybe? what if you're not linking the props to the state right?